# Static integer losing it's value in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

Static integer resetting it's value after revisiting activity with timer. And also transition is kind of glitchy. I think that the problem is in "OnFinish". And also as soon as timer riches 0 it prints out error. But it doesn't effect app. It doesn't crashes or something:

```
Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
```

Here's my first activity code:

```
public class Begin extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Integer num = 1;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    public static final String NUM = "num";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin);
}

public void start_button(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeginAfter.class);{
            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(NUM, String.valueOf(num++));
            editor.apply();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my second activity with timer:

```
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%01d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));
                textView.setText(sDuration);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                startActivity(new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begin.class));
                }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and store the 'num' variable there, so every time you visit the Begin class, just retrieve its value/ update it, etc.

Comment: I updated my code. Used Shared Preferences but still didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is this error that it prints out when timer is finished. idk why it gives this error